# Generating a single string with an Oxford comma from a list

Tags: code-golf, string, array

What are some clever (brief and idiomatic) approaches to taking a list of strings and returning a single properly punctuated string built from the list, with each element quoted.

This came up for me while [experimenting with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25793522/656912), for which my too-literal, but illustrative solution is

```
def temp = things.collect({"\'${it}\'"})
switch (things.size()) {
    case 1:
        result = temp[0]
        break
    case 2:
        result = temp.join(" and ")
        break
    default:
        result = temp.take(temp.size()-1).join(", ") + ", and " + temp[-1]
        break
}
```

That is, `['1']` should yield `'1'`, `['1','2']` should yield `'1 and 2'`, [see what I did there?] and `['1','2','3']` should yield `'1, 2, and 3'`.

I have some good answers for Groovy, but I'd like to see what other languages can do.

What are some *compact* clever approaches in various languages that take advantage of the features and idioms of those languages?

Comment: Input is an Array of characters or a single string. i.e. `['1','2']` or `"['1', '2']"`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.  Generally questions posted here are challenges to the community.  As such they need an objective winning criteria.  I believe this question maps reasonably well to being a [tag:code-golf] challenge.  Can you tag it as such?  If so, I think you should tighten up the input and output specifications a bit.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Good suggestion. Thanks. I'd like it to focus on producing the most *idiomatic code*; that is, the code that takes best advantage of the capabilities of the language. Is that a fair challenge (and of so, how should I tag it)?

Comment: @Optimizer: An array of characters (of of strings).

Comment: @MartinBüttner: For here, I'll go with length ([tag:code-golf]) then.

Comment: This would be more interesting with [real sentences](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qpg3UFOQzhI/TupPzcLeQZI/AAAAAAAAADI/IReqJR8DWy8/s1600/oxford+comma.png): `['we invited the stripper','JFK','Stalin']`

Comment: Can we assume that the strings themselves don't contain commas already?

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Good question. Assume not: no commas or "and"s to mess things up.

Comment: Do we need to make it a complete CLI-executable solution? Must it be wrapped in a function declaration, or just the relevant code with setup instructions? Is the setup included in the scoring size?

Comment: Challenge should have been titled "Who gives a ---- about an [Oxford comma](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_i1xk07o4g)?"

Comment: My old English teacher would be horrified to see a comma before an "and". The last result should read `'1, 2 and 3'` to be proper *English* English rather than the Americanised rubbish spoken in the colonies. :)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I think you mean "Americanized rubbish" ;)

Answer (score 77):

## CSS, <s>132</s> <s>116</s> 115 bytes

```css
a:not(:last-child):nth-child(n+2):after,a:nth-last-child(n+3):after{content:","}a+:last-child:before{content:"and "
```

```html
<p>
  <a>one</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four</a>
</p>
```

```css
a:not(:last-child):nth-child(n+2):after,a:nth-last-child(n+3):after{content:","}a+:last-child:before{content:"and "
```

CSS is not seen too often in code golf because it can only format text, but it actually works for this challenge and I thought it would be fun to do. See it in action using the snippet above (click "Show code snippet").

List should be in a linked HTML file with each element surrounded by `<a>` tags and separated by line breaks. The list items should be the only elements in their parent element, e.g.

```html
<a>one</a>
<a>two</a>
<a>three</a>
```

### Explanation

```css
a:not(:last-child):nth-child(n+2)::after,
a:nth-last-child(n+3)::after {
    content: ",";
}

a + :last-child::before {
    content: "and ";
}
```

Let's consider the ungolfed version above. If you're not familiar with how CSS works, everything outside the curly braces is a selector that determines the set of HTML elements to which the declarations inside the braces apply. Each selector-declaration pair is called a *rule*. (It's more complicated than that but will suffice for this explanation.) Before any styling is applied, the list appears separated by only spaces.

We want to add commas after every word except the last, except for two-word lists, which get no commas. The first selector, `a:not(:last-child):nth-child(n+2):after`, selects all elements except the first and the last. `:nth-child(n+2)` is a shorter way of saying `:not(:first-child)`, and it basically works by selecting elements whose index (starting at 1) is greater than or equal to 2. (Yes, it still confuses me a little. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) might help.)

Now we just need to select the first element to get a comma *if* there are three or more elements total. `a:nth-last-child(n+3):after` works like `:nth-child`, but counting from the back, so it selects all elements except the last two. The comma takes the union of the two sets, and we use the `:after` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to add `content` immediately after each selected element.

The second rule is easier. We need to add "and" before the last element in the list, unless it is a single element. In other words, we need to select the last element that is preceded by another element. `+` is the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) in CSS.

Comment: Brilliant! I love it. :D

Comment: If only you'd use `<li>`.

Comment: `<li>` would be ideal, but that would add two extra characters to the selectors. I chose `<a>` because it is one letter and doesn't apply its own formatting.

Comment: Wow... this is very impressive. Cleverness award.

Comment: CSS as the top answer? Nice.

Comment: 89b => http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37653/generating-a-single-string-with-an-oxford-comma-from-a-list/37796#37796

Comment: Why do you need line breaks? HTML is supposed to just treat them like a space.

Comment: @trlkly The line breaks eliminate the need for adding spaces to the CSS code because they are automatically converted to spaces.

Answer (score 13):

## Haskell: <s>81, 77</s> 74 chars

```
f[x]=x
f[x,y]=x++" and "++y
f[x,y,z]=x++", "++f[y++",",z]
f(x:y)=x++", "++f y
```

Haskell features: Pattern matching

Comment: You can remove some spaces

Comment: You could just remove `f[x,y,z]`

Comment: And now, it is pretty much standard recursion. :)

Comment: you forgot the oxford comma and spaces after the commas - `f["a","b","c"]` is supposed to be `"a, b, and c"` but it is `"a,b and c"`

Comment: also you could golf a bit by replacing `" "++f y` by `' ':f y`

Comment: @proudhaskeller Is it still possible with the version including whitespace?

Comment: you still need to add the actual oxford comma :). also, you better cut out the old incorrect version (it is still visible in the edit history). about the `',':` optimization, unfortunately not.

Comment: Currently it gives `1, 2, 3,  and 4`

Comment: @Sieg not on my computer, and not as simulated by my mind

Comment: @proudhaskeller Now the correct version is there again.

Comment: how about golfing by replacing `y++", and "++z` by `f[y++",",z]` :)

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, 47 bytes

```
q=" and ";p$*[2]?(a=$*.pop;$**", "+?,+q+a):$**q
```

#### Explanation

- The input are the command line arguments (`$*`).
- When `$*` has a third element (`$*[2]` does not return nil), take all elements minus the last one and turn them into a comma-separated String using `Array#*`. Finally add an extra comma, the string `" and "` and the last command line argument.
- When `$*` has no third element, two, one, or zero arguments were given. The arguments can safely be joined with the string `" and "` and produce the correct result.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2 (61)

```python
s=input()
d=s.pop()
print", ".join(s)+", and "[8-7*len(s):]+d
```

The main trick is to cut off part of the final joiner `", and "` for one and two elements. For one, all of it is cut out, and for two, the comma is removed. This is done by slicing out `[8-7*len(s):]` (noting that `s` is one shorter after the `pop`).

Unfortunately, `d` cannot just be replaced with its expression or the `pop` would happen too late.

Comment: You could replace the first `s` with `s=input()` and remove the first line, if I'm not mistaken. Saves 2 chars.

Comment: @tomsmeding I don't understand what you're suggesting. The code is referring to `s` multiple times.

Comment: Wait, I do weird stuff this morning. Forget that. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Perl (v 5.10+) - <s>37</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 28

```
@F>2&&s/ /, /g;s/.* \K/and /
```

to be run with `perl -ape`, with the list supplied space separated on `STDIN`.

Output for various inputs:

```
$ perl -ape '@F>2&&s/ /, /g;s/.* \K/and /'
oxford
oxford
oxford cambridge
oxford and cambridge
oxford cambridge comma
oxford, cambridge, and comma
oxford cambridge comma space
oxford, cambridge, comma, and space
```

Comment: You can reduce this by 3 bytes by changing your last substitution to `s/(\S+)$/and $1/`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You can drop the '\n' (thanks), but you can't drop the spaces, or an input of "x" becomes "and x"

Comment: Oops, should have tested with more inputs. Anyway, you forgot the `$` anchor in your edit, so an input of `foo bar baz` becomes `foo, and bar, baz`. Also, you can remove *one* of the spaces by doing `s/( \S+)$/ and$1/`

Comment: My last comment still leaves you at 35, but you can write `$#F>1` as `@F>2` to shave off one more. Sorry for all the suggestions for micro improvements, I just really like this answer :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot not at all - microedits welcome. I am secretly competing with 28 bytes of CJam and 30 bytes of Golfscript. However I did get to 34 without doing the translation of your comment before last (tested with `echo -n ... | wc -c)`. If you miss the space before `(\S+)` you'd get to 33 characters, but if you put in `test this` you will get `test  and this` (two spaces after `test`), so without more I think that's wrong.

Comment: Okay, two more: replacing the second regex with `s/.* \K/and /` drops you down by 4 (requires Perl 5.10), and replacing the conditional operator with `&&` shaves off one, for a grand total of 29! Take that, Golfscript! `@F>2&&s/ /, /g;s/.* \K/and /`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: you have excelled yourself. That's actually 28 not 29. I thought I tried `&&` earlier and had operator precedence issues, but I obviously failed. Didn't think of `\K`. And WOAH! Tied with CJam! Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I guess I can't count. I *knew* Perl could hold its own in golf, though. I tried a lot of different approaches and yours was better than all of them, so kudos. All I did was tidy up a bit :P

Answer (score 6):

## CSS, <del>62 chars</del> 112 chars

Inspired by the other entries, even shorter. Note that it requires that A elements are not separated by white spaces:

```
a+a:before{content:", "}a+a:last-child:before{content:", and "
```

http://jsfiddle.net/olvlvl/1Ls79ocb/

Fix for the "one and two", as pointed at by Dennis:

```
a+a:before{content:", "}a+a:last-child:before{content:", and "}a:first-child+a:last-child:before{content:" and "
```

http://jsfiddle.net/olvlvl/1Ls79ocb/3/

Answer (score 4):

## GNU sed -  69 chars including 1 for `-r` flag

```
s/ /, /g
s/( [^ ]+)( [^ ]+)$/\1 and\2/
s/^([^,]+),([^,]+)$/\1 and\2/
```

Takes a space-separated list (fairly idiomatic for shell scripts).

### Example

```
$ sed -r -f oxfordcomma.sed <<< "1"
1
$ sed -r -f oxfordcomma.sed <<< "1 2"
1 and 2
$ sed -r -f oxfordcomma.sed <<< "1 2 3"
1, 2, and 3
$
```

Comment: Yes, let's go with [tag:code-golf].

Comment: The second output should be `1 and 2` instead of `1, 2`

Comment: @Optimizer - quite right.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (63)

`l=a.length;l>2&&(a[l-1]='and '+a[l-1]);a.join(l>2?', ':' and ')`

Cases:

- `a = [1]` => `1`
- `a = [1, 2]` => `1 and 2`
- `a = [1, 2, 3]` => `1, 2, and 3`

Caveat: this will modify the last element in an array with length > 2.

Comment: Nice use of `&&`

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy, <s>47 43</s> 57 characters , JavaScript ES6 56 characters

**Groovy:**

```
(a[1]?a[0..-2].join(", ")+(a[2]?",":"")+" and ":"")+a[-1]
```

Since the array is filled with characters, we can replace `a.size>1` by `a[1]`

**JavaScript, ES6:**

```
a.join(', ').replace(/,([^,]+)$/,`${a[2]?',':''} and$1`)
```

Both cases assume that variable a has the array in question.

Comment: The Oxford comma *is* the comma before the conjunction.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 - <s>71, 70</s> 68

```
s=input()
l=len(s)-1
print', '.join(s[:l])+', and '[l<2:]*(l>0)+s[l]
```

Character count including both, `input` and `print`.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>35</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
q~)\_"and "L?@+a+_,2=", ">*
```

This is a program that reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### How it works

```
q~                                     " Q := eval(input())                               ";
  )                                    " P := Q.pop()                                     ";
   \_"and "L?@+                        " P := (Q ? 'and ' : '') + P                       ";
                a+                     " Q += [P]                                         ";
                  _,2=", ">            " J := ', '[(len(Q) == 2):]                        ";
                           *           " R := J.join(Q)                                   ";
                                       " print R (implicit)                               ";
```

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo 'q~)\_"and "L?@+a+_,2=", ">*') <<< '["1"]'; echo
1
$ cjam <(echo 'q~)\_"and "L?@+a+_,2=", ">*') <<< '["1""2"]'; echo
1 and 2
$ cjam <(echo 'q~)\_"and "L?@+a+_,2=", ">*') <<< '["1""2""3"]'; echo
1, 2, and 3
$ cjam <(echo 'q~)\_"and "L?@+a+_,2=", ">*') <<< '["1""2""3""4"]'; echo
1, 2, 3, and 4
```

Comment: I am on your tail - see below :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 57 bytes

```
f=->l{s=l*', ';s.sub(/,(?!.*,)/,(l.size<3?'':?,)+' and')}
```

I'm joining the string with `,` and then I'm replacing the last comma in the string with an `and` (and optional comma depending on list length).

Answer (score 3):

## Cobra - 60

```
do(l as String[])=l.join(', ',if(l.length<3,'',',')+' and ')
```

Cobra's `List<of T>.join` function lets you specify a different separator for the final two elements of the list, which is what makes this so short.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch - 151 Bytes

```
@echo off&set f=for %%a in (%~1)do
%f% set/aa+=1
%f% set/ac+=1&if !c!==1 (set o=%%a)else if !c!==!a! (set o=!o!, and %%a)else set o=!o!, %%a
echo !o!
```

Note; you have to call the script from `cmd` with the `/v` switch set as `on`, this is so I don't have to include the lengthy `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` in the script. Otherwise add 30 to the byte count, and call the script normally.

```
h:\uprof>cmd /von /c test.bat "1 2 3"
1, 2, and 3

h:\uprof>cmd /von /c test.bat "1 2 3 4 5"
1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>192</s> <s>167</s> <s>146</s> 136 characters:

```
$n=' and ';$s=count($a);echo ($s<3)?join($n,$a):join(', ',array_merge(array_slice($a,0,$s-2),Array(join(",$n",array_slice($a,-2,2)))));
```

Based on a function I wrote years ago at http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/05/21/join-implode-an-array-of-string-values-with-formatting/

Comment: Can you please put your code (with Oxford commas) into the answer text?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was on my phone and it wouldn't paste the code properly. I'll update from my desktop

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 even if it is trivial to add, the answer should include a working code, not one that can be made to be one. also, because the objective is to make the code as smaller as possible, not posting working code makes your score non existing.

Comment: Apologies again. First time poster at CG. I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - 59

```
sub f{$a=join', ',@_;$#_&&substr$a,(@_>2)-3,@_<3,' and';$a}
```

Joins the list with commas, then if the list has more than one element, either adds `' and'` after the last comma (if length >= 3), or replaces the last comma with it (if length == 2).

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>86</s> 84 chars

```
$a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
```

With the array initialized, we start counting:

```
$L=count($a)-1;$S=', ';$L<2?($S=' and '):($a[$L]='and '.$a[$L]);echo implode($S,$a);
```

Prettified:

```
$last_index = count($a) - 1;
$separator = ', ';
if ($last_index < 2) {
    $separator = ' and ';
} else {
    $a[$last_index] = 'and '.$a[$last_index];
}
echo implode($separator, $a);
```

The last item in the list is modified. This should be OK because in PHP, array assignment and function calls perform copies.

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, <s>67</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 92 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(", ",FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),",",IF(COUNTA(A:A)>2,",","")&" and",COUNTA(A:A)-1
```

The input starts at cell `A1` and continuing down for however many entries exist.
`JOIN` merges them all into a string with a comma-space between each.
`FILTER` removes any non-blanks so you don't end up with infinite commas at the end.
`SUBSTITUTE` replaces the last comma (found by `COUNTA` counting the non-blank inputs).

It's not very exciting but it's doable in a single cell.

Comment: This leaves out the oxford comma.

Comment: @Umbrella Well, that was stupid of me, wasn't it? +1 bytes

Comment: You should be able to drop the terminal `)` off of this formula for -1 Byte; Well dang, that was the quickest edit I've ever seen +1

Comment: Two notes after testing this - `A:A>""` should be converted to `A:A<>""` and this does not implement omitting the oxford comma on cases of only 2 objects

Comment: @TaylorScott I guess I only ever tested with text and missed the issue with `>""`. The quickie correction I made earlier clearly wasn't tested. I don't like the direction *that* went...

Comment: I get what you mean - if you take a look at my solution's edits you can see where I realized I forgot the case of only 2 objects and ended up having to add some 40 bytes just to correct for it

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 27 bytes

```
ṫ$:[`λ¬ `pJ:Ḣ₃[÷ð$Ṡ|‛, j]|_
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%AB%24%3A%5B%60%CE%BB%C2%AC%20%60pJ%3A%E1%B8%A2%E2%82%83%5B%C3%B7%C3%B0%24%E1%B9%A0%7C%E2%80%9B%2C%20j%5D%7C_&inputs=%5B1%5D&header=&footer=)

```
ṫ                           # Tail extract (x[:-1], x[-1] )
 $:[                        # If length > 1
    `λ¬ `p                  # Prepend a 'and '
          J                 # Merge
           :Ḣ₃[             # If length = 2
               ÷ð$Ṡ         # Add in a space and join
                   |    ]   # Else...
                    ‛, j    # Join by ', '
                         |_ # Else pop
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 60

Assuming no empty strings in input array

```
f=(a,b=a.pop())=>a[0]?a.join(', ')+(a[1]?',':'')+' and '+b:b
```

**Test** In FireFox/Firebug console

```
console.log(f(['We invited the stripper','JFK','Stalin']))
```

*Output*

```
 We invited the stripper, JFK, and Stalin
```

Comment: How do I run this? I tried it in `node --harmony` with an array of strings `var a = 'abcdefgh'.split('');`, but it just sits there with a `...` and appears to do nothing. Also +1 for using unique ES6 feature `()=>`.

Comment: @Adrian the function returns a string, without any output. I'll add a test in the answer.

Comment: I think `f=(a,b=a.pop())=>a[0]?a.join(', ')+', and '+b:b` is also correct and 13 bytes shorter.

Comment: @IngoBürk that cuts the part that handles the comma having 2 items. Guess what? With 2 items the output is wrong.

Comment: @edc65 Ah, d'oh. May bad.

Comment: @edc65 Thanks -- I simultaneously knew and forgot that `()=>` was a function definition, so simply pasting it in would have no effect. :/

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript - <s>60</s> <s>56</s> <s>71</s> <s>67</s> 63

Not exactly an idiomatic approach, but I had fun writing it and I like regex.

Assuming the array is stored in `var a`:

```
a.join((a.length>2?',':'')+' ').replace(/([^,\s])$/,"and $1")
```

Shortened by simply checking for index `[2]`: (yay boolean coercion)

```
a.join((!!a[2]?',':'')+' ').replace(/([^,\s])$/,'and $1')
```

Apparently I suck at testing and skipped a single-entry test. Here's the fixed version:

```
a.join((!!a[2]?',':'')+' ').replace(/([^,\s])$/,(!!a[1]?'and ':'')+'$1')
```

Shaved off 2 chars by inverting my booleans and 3 more by moving the space from the concatenation into the then/else of the first ternary:

```
a.join((!a[2]?' ':', ')).replace(/([^,\s])$/,(!a[1]?'':'and ')+'$1')
```

Thanks to @tomsmeding for reminding me that I don't have to coerce my booleans because JS does that for me. I also realised I forgot to remove the parentheses separating the first ternary from the concatenation inside the `join()`:

```
a.join(a[2]?', ':' ').replace(/([^,\s])$/,(a[1]?'and ':'')+'$1')
```

Did I do that right? Obligatory new golfer apology.

Comment: Liking regex is known as masochism.

Comment: Actually you didn't need the `!!` at all; `a[2]?A:B` works already. Might have to invert your booleans _again_.

Comment: @tomsmeding -- you are correct. I am always wary of JavaScript's default boolean coercion behaviour, so I have the borne-in habit of manually coercing my booleans...

Comment: @Adrian Correction: for any value but an empty string, `a[i]` equates to ***true***. Well, almost. I'm assuming that if you get 2 inputs, your array has length two. Then `a[2]===undefined` and `undefined` evaluates to `false`. EDIT: your edit is what I meant :)

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript - <strike>31</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>34</strike> 30

Hello, World! I am a long time lurker, first time poster. Here is my 30 byte solution in Golfscript (given the array such as [1 2 3] is already on the stack).

```
.,3<" and ":A{~A(;\+]", "}if*
```

The results are proper for all test cases.

EDIT: Take that, CJam!

Comment: Edited to account for the length 1 array.

Comment: Edited for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: The battle continues. :P

Comment: Ah, but now we're even. :P

Answer (score 2):

## Xojo, <s>52</s> <s>71</s> 83 chars

```
dim i as int8=ubound(L)
L(i)=if(i=0,"","and ")+L(i)
Return L.Join(if(i=1," ",", ")
```

Note that UBound is one less than the array length.

Comment: This seems to add the comma when there are 2 items - should not

Comment: Good catch. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 108 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as space delimited array from range `A1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
x=Split([A1]):y=UBound(x):For i=0To y-2:?x(i)", ";:Next:If y>0Then?x(i)IIf(y>1,",","")" and "x(i+1)Else?[A1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket 87

```
(define(f x)(string-join(map ~a x)", "#:before-last(if(= 2(length x))" and "", and ")))
```

Comment: I still find the function names in lisps to be way too long for golfing.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 62 chars

Assuming that i is the list of strings:

```
(" and", ", and")[len(i) < 2].join(", ".join(i).rsplit(",",1))
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# 102 Chars**

```
var i=m.Count(),l=i;if(l>2)l--;var r=string.Join(", ",m.Take(l));if(l!=i)r+=" and "+m.Last();return r;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia (53)

```
print(join(ARGS,", ",(endof(ARGS)>2?",":"")" and "))
```

Takes args from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT

Solution using Base.join(items, delim[, last])

Edit:

Test cases

```
julia oxfordComma.jl 1
```

1

```
julia oxfordComma.jl 1 2
```

1 and 2

```
julia oxfordComma.jl 1 2 3
```

1, 2, and 3

Comment: I don't know Julia, but this looks like it doesn't generate the Oxford comma.

Comment: @flornquake it does print with the Oxford comma, due to the optional "last" argument

Comment: It should be `1, 2, and 3`, not `1, 2 and 3`.

Answer (score 1):

## Rant (108)

```
[$[l:@b]:[r:each][s:[cmp:[rc];2;[is:different;,]]\s][before:[last:[notfirst:and\s]]][sync:;ordered][arg:b]]
```

Ungolfed:

```
[$[l:@b]:
    [r:each]                            # Repeat for each item
    [s:[cmp:[rc];2;[is:different;,]]\s] # Separate by comma if n > 2
    [before:[last:[notfirst:and\s]]]    # Insert "and" before last item
    [sync:;ordered]                     # Force forward order
    [arg:b]                             # Read list
]
```

Usage:

```
[$l:{A|B|C|D|E}]
```

[Try it online](http://berkin.me/rantbox#6734D3D88CF16B473F6BE7F4CAF8586B36E0AFAE)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 28

```
j>", "qlQ2+_t_Q+?"and "tQkeQ
```

#### Examples:

```
$ pyth programs/oxford.pyth <<< "['1']"
1

$ pyth programs/oxford.pyth <<< "['1','2']"
1 and 2

$ pyth programs/oxford.pyth <<< "['1','2','3']"
1, 2, and 3
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how the input should be formatted.

Comment: @Dennis I'll add some test cases.

Comment: I had actually tried that, but it didn't work with my version of Pyth (`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`). It works fine with the latest version.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, the adding to list rule was added quite recently.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 67 bytes

```
f[n]=n
f[m,n]=m++" and "++n
f n=(init n>>=(++", "))++"and "++last n
```

Abuses the list monad a bit

### Explanation

Doing this later

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 79 chars

Note: the char count does not include the list declaration.

```
l=['1','2','3']
print l[0] if len(l)<2 else (', '.join(l[:-1])+(',' if len(l)>2 else '')+' and '+l[-1])
```

Output for various inputs:

```
1
1 and 2
1, 2, and 3
...
```

Comment: i understand why you don't count the declaration (though that is the reason i'm personally against hardcoding input when op doesn't specifically say it's okay) but i'm interested in your justification for not counting `print`

Comment: @undergroundmonorail The title reads 'generating a string' and the specification reads 'should yield' with nothing said about printing said string.

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript (61)

The fact that Javascript and others score better pretty much shows that this is probably not done very efficiently in terms of golfing.

```
.,.2={;' and '*}{(\{\(.{.)', '''if}{', and '}if@\+print}/;}if
```

Examples with link to try it out:

- [["1"] -> "1"](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O1siMSJdCi4sLjI9ezsnIGFuZCAnKn17KFx7XCguey4pJywgJycnaWZ9eycsIGFuZCAnfWlmQFwrcHJpbnR9Lzt9aWY%3D)
- [["1" "2"] -> "1 and 2"](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O1siMSIgIjIiXQouLC4yPXs7JyBhbmQgJyp9eyhce1woLnsuKScsICcnJ2lmfXsnLCBhbmQgJ31pZkBcK3ByaW50fS87fWlm)
- [["1" "2" "3"] -> "1, 2, and 3"](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O1siMSIgIjIiICIzIl0KLiwuMj17OycgYW5kICcqfXsoXHtcKC57LiknLCAnJydpZn17JywgYW5kICd9aWZAXCtwcmludH0vO31pZg%3D%3D)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 + Moose, 70 bytes

```
sub english_list{@_<3?join" and ",@_:do{$_="and ".pop;join", ",@_,$_}}
```

Not many people seem to know it, but Moose, the popular OO framework for Perl 5, has a function to do this built in. (Moose uses it internally in its error messages, but exposes it as a documented, public function.)

```
my @l = (1 .. 3);
use Moose;
print Moose::Util::english_list(@l);
```

Excluding the definition of the list `@l`, that can be easily golfed down to 41 characters. If you allow the use of the `say` function which was introduced in Perl 5.10, you can knock off two more characters. (I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.)

Now, looking at the definition of the `english_list` function itself, the best I've been able to golf it down to is 70 characters:

```
sub english_list{@_<3?join" and ",@_:do{$_="and ".pop;join", ",@_,$_}}
```

... though obviously by choosing a shorter function name, that could be reduced further. (59 characters if you choose a one-letter function name.)

Comment: Use `perl -ane` and `use Moose;say Moose::Util::english_list(@F)` but that is still 44 characters. You can use the same `@F` trick for your function.

Comment: You're missing a couple of tricks... `say Moose'Util'english_list@F`

Comment: Perl has anonymous functions, and those are acceptable answers here. You can just start with `sub{`, and not give it a name at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 221 chars

This is not a compact implementation, but the usage is tight: it overrides `toString()` for `ArrayList` via meta-class functionality (and maps - no conditionals here!).

This is powerful stuff, but idiomatic when writing a framework. That is, the change is transparent to the client.

Golfed (assumes variable `a` is defined):

```
q={s->"'$s'"}
r={q a[it]}
f={"${it[0..-2].join ", "}, and ${it[-1]}"}
m=[:].withDefault{f}
m[0]={""}
m[1]={r 0}
m[2]={"${r 0} and ${r 1}"}
ArrayList.metaClass.toString={->m[delegate.size()].call(delegate.collect{q(it)})}
```

Sample assertions:

```
a=['oxford','cambridge','comma','space']
assert "'oxford', 'cambridge', 'comma', and 'space'" == a.toString()

a=['oxford','cambridge']
assert "'oxford' and 'cambridge'" == a.toString()

a=['oxford']
assert "'oxford'" == a.toString()

a=[]
assert "" == a.toString()
```

Ungolfed:

```
q = {s->"'$s'"}
r = {q a[it]}

f = {"${it[0..-2].join ", "}, and ${it[-1]}"}
m = [:].withDefault{f}
m[0] = {""}
m[1] = {r 0}
m[2] = {"${r 0} and ${r 1}"}

ArrayList.metaClass.toString = { ->
    m[ delegate.size() ].call( delegate.collect{q(it)} )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash (79)

```
(($#<3))&&echo $1 ${2/#/and }||{ Y=${@/%/,};L=${@: -1};echo ${Y/%$L,/and $L}; }
```

### Explaination

For 1 or 2 parameters

- echo $1 and, if $2 exists, prefix $2 with "and ".

Otherwise

- suffix all parameters with a comma and join together
- get last parameter
- replace "$L," with "and $L"

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 67

```
if($c=count($a)-1)$a[$c]='and '.$a[$c];echo join($c-1?', ':' ',$a);
```

If there's more than one item, prepend the last with `'and '`.  (store the count minus one in `$c`).

Next, join on space or comma space, depending on whether the count is two.

```
if ($c = count($a) - 1) {
    $a[$c] = 'and '.$a[$c];
}
echo join($c - 1 ? ', ' : ' ', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 80 bytes

```
DEF L A
L=LEN(A)WHILE LEN(A)>1?SHIFT(A);","*(L>2);" ";
WEND?"and "*(L>1);A[0]END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->*f,l{f[0]?f*', '+(f[1]??,:'')+' and '+l:l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run//##KypNqvyfbvtf104rTSenOi3aINY@TUtdR0FdWyMt2jDW3l7HSl1dU1tdITEvBSiYY5VT@7@gtKRYIT1a3VA9lgvBBuoxwhQAEsY4RIGECT4pIGGqHvsfAA)